# Samba mount-point with Nautilus

Tags: gnome, samba, gvfs

I'm trying to access by command line to the shares automatically mounted by Nautilus (I'm on a RHEL6), but I'm unable to find the mount point. Googling around I found that I should look in `~/.gvfs`, but it is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It changed some time ago. Recently I have been finding my network shares in:
`/run/user/*user-id*>/gvfs`
or
`/var/run/user/*user-id*/gvfs`

The user-id might also be your user name.